# Access Azure Embedded Binary Resource (FileStream?)

Tags: c#, azure, filestream, embedded-resource

I have some code that uses FileStream to quickly read from a binary file.  My test project console app works great pointing at a local file.  My production environment is ASP.NET MVC on Azure, and so I figured that I should use a resource file.  Currently the code is:

```
var file = new FileStream(@"c:\path\myfile.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

...

Do I need to migrate the code to use something other than FileStream, or is there a way?  Speed is a key requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.  This was easy.  I simply needed to use MemoryStream instead.
var ms = new MemoryStream(MyAssembly.Properties.Resources.Resource, false);

MemoryStream and FileStream both inherit from Stream, so the rest of the code didn't have to change...